# Yii Project: How I can prevent from loading related model(child) for a (parent) model?

Tags: php, yii, relationship, yii-cmodel

Salam(Hi),
How I can prevent from loading related model(child) for a (parent) model?

Comment: No one can help?! My problem is the true yet!!

Answer (score 0):

How do you know they are loaded with parent model? Have you checked the LogRoute? (Uncomment it in the config)

```
'log' => array(
    'class' => 'CLogRouter',
    'routes' => array(
        ...
        array(
            'class' => 'CWebLogRoute',
            'categories' => 'system.db.*',
            'except' => 'system.db.ar.*',
        ),
```

**Related models are not loaded by default** (if you haven't used `with('relatedModel')` method).

Any related records will be lazy loaded when accessing the relation property the first time.
[http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7430-lazy-loading-of-many-many-relations/page_*view*_findpost_*p*_37674](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7430-lazy-loading-of-many-many-relations/page__view__findpost__p__37674)

Comment: 1. I haven't use with('relatedModel') method.

Comment: 2. Have checked the LogRoute and I see the child models query executed for each parent model!!!

Comment: in that case it's lazy loading... Probably you are accessing the relation property that is not loaded. Or?

Comment: this is my code: ParentModel::model()->findAll(); and it run 7 queries. 3 for ParentModel and 4 for relatedModel!

Comment: Are you accessing some related property in view?

Comment: no, I put an exit() after that code (for test) and no view rendered!!